# Nested "Formal" Block Determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

I found this interesting formula on Wikipedia on blocked determinant of a square matrix:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21}
\end{vmatrix}$$ provided that $A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ commute.

Does anyone know of the obvious generalization of this formula? That is, is determinant of a matrix $A$ that is blocked into $n^2$ matrices $A_{11}, A_{12}, \cdots, A_{nn}$ equal to determinant of a "formal determinant" (computed using the [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants)) by treating $A_{11}, A_{12} ,\cdots, A_{nn}$ as if they are scalars? (Here of course we assume that the blocking is done such that multiplications in the Leibniz formula make sense) Since the original formula involved conditions that $A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ commute, there are probably conditions to make this formal blocked determinant thing work.